# How do you create breakpoints in IE Developer Tools for code that runs while loading?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

So I have this web page I need to debug in IE (9). I'd like to use the Developer Tools. I need to create a breakpoint inside code that runs while the page is loading.

The problem is that even if I set a breakpoint, when I reload the page it will be erased, as this is a new context.

If said code only ran after some given action, I could create the breakpoint and only trigger the action afterwards. But it runs while loading, so no luck.

The `debugger;` statement could do what I want, but it triggers the VS Debug with... dialog, in which the only option is VS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've been doing this for quite a bit, here is the procedure I follow:

1. Put your `debugger;` line wherever you need it to be in your
   javascript code.
2. Open up IE and **BEFORE** loading your page and press F12 to bring
   up the Dev Tools
3. In the Dev Tools, click on the Script tab and press the `Start
   Debugging` button. This will make the Dev tools aware of any
   breakpoints you have specified.
4. Load up your webpage and the Dev Tool should pick up the
   debugger statement.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Hector. That's just what was needed. And here I was, convinced there was no solution!

Comment: But what if we do not have control over code, i. e. we can put `debugger`?