# See what JS it executed in background? [IE only]

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to manipulate the Developer tools to show me the actual JS code being run in background, to no success. Is this even possible to do? (IE only)

Thanks!

Comment: Ever since at least IE 5 you've been able to breakpoint and step through javascript in IE. Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931366/how-do-you-create-breakpoints-in-ie-developer-tools-for-code-that-runs-while-loa

Comment: What do you mean by "background"?

Comment: @Bergi - in my case, when I select a dropdown in a form, the page is automatically saved. However, I don't know what function is being executed to save the data, and what variables are being passed. That's what I meant by `background`.

Comment: @pufAmuf Put the string `debugger;` in the code where the code is supposed to run - run step by step, JavaScript is single threaded.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum if he doesn't know where to put the debugger - that won't help

Comment: @YuriyGalanter as the very first thing that loads in the page..

Comment: @pufAmuf: You have to debug the event listeners of that element (specifically the `onchange` handlers in your case). In most devtools you can set breakpoints for events, yet I don't know IE.

Comment: this question make little sense...please re-phrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the real-time no. But starting with IE8 you can start Script profiling, run your pages and then after stopping profile you can see everything that was run, neatly arranged.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Setting breakpoints in F12 tools is similar to binary code debuggers like Microsoft Visual Studio. In the left pane, click to the left of the line of code you want to break on. Breakpoints are toggled, so you click to add them, and click again to remove them.

[image]

Hope this helps. You can read more at [Breaking Code Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#breaking_code_execution)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, running in the background is only something you can do with `web workers`.  So you might want to re-phrase your question so it makes more sense in this context.

Next, IE 10+, will put your code into JavaScript blocks which you can look at.  All the code in the "blocks" has been loaded into memory.

From there, you can debug as needed.